# C++ library causing crash in native Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am learning how to implement C++ projects into native Android and found myself a C++ library to import. Everything works great, but the problem is when `onBackPressed()` is called, the user is directed to the previous fragment as expected, but when they re-enter the Activity which is populated by the C++ library, a crash happens.

The only error I am given is `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 9408 (GLThread 27055), pid 9296 (fluidSimulation)`

I started to do some digging in the `gl_code.cpp` file where I pass values to exposed C++ methods and I believe I have identified the issue, but I am stuck on a fix...

There is the following C++ method that is called each time the Activity is created:

```
//This is global as it is used in other methods
void *fluid; 

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_ui_fluidSimulation_FluidLib_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint width,
                                                  jint height) {
    fluid = fluidCreate((int) width, (int) height);
}
```

Now, I have figured out that the `fluid` pointer is being held in memory after the activity is exited when `onBackPressed()` is called. I have worked out that this method needs to be called each time the activity starts, but I need to understand how to reset the pointer.

I have tried `delete fluid;` before calling `fluidCreate`, but this doesn't work. Is there a work around for this problem or am I at the mercy of the library and better off abandoning it?

**UPDATE 1**

So, every frame the below method is called and I have noticed the crash happens when the fluid is added to the frame.

```
static double now_ms(void) {

    struct timespec res;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res);
    return 1000.0 * res.tv_sec + (double) res.tv_nsec / 1e6;

}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_ui_fluidSimulation_FluidLib_step(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    double t = now_ms();
    //Below is printed
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Gets before fluidOnFrame");
    fluidOnFrame(fluid, t);
    //Below is is not printed
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Gets after fluidOnFrame");
}
```

These methods are called in Native Android as follows:

```
private class Renderer : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10) {
        FluidLib.step()
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) {

        FluidLib.init(width, height)

    }

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

The methods used are defined as follows:

```
object FluidLib {
/**
 * @param width the current view width
 * @param height the current view height
 */
external fun init(width: Int, height: Int)
external fun destroy()
external fun step()

init {
    System.loadLibrary("gl_code")
  }
}
```

My file to interact with the C++ library:

```
/**
 * C-Style API to enable the fluid component to be used with C-based clients (i.e. Swift)
 */

#ifndef Fluid_h
#define Fluid_h

enum PointerType {
    MOUSE = 0,
    TOUCH = 1,
    PEN = 2
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void* fluidCreate(int width, int height);  
    void fluidOnFrame(void* fluidPtr, double frameTime_ms);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* Fluid_h */
```

**UPDATE 2**

To try to understand the cause of the problem better, I ended up creating an if statement around my `fluidCreate` method to see if it was the pointer or some other issue as follows:

```
void *fluid;
void *newFluid;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL

Java_com_android_ui_fluidSimulation_FluidLib_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint width,
                                                  jint height) {

    if(fluid == 0) {
        fluid = fluidCreate((int) width, (int) height);
    }else{
        newFluid = fluidCreate((int) width, (int) height);
    }

}
```

Then did the following on my method that's called each frame:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_ui_fluidSimulation_FluidLib_step(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    double t = now_ms();

    if(newFluid == 0) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Original Fluid on Frame");
        fluidOnFrame(fluid, t);
    }else{
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "New Fluid on Frame");
        fluidOnFrame(newFluid, t);
    }
}
```

Now, even though different pointers are used, the crash is still caused, which makes me think that there seems to be a bug in the C++ library `fluidOnFrame` method...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the right direction. The crash log looks like a memory exception to me as well and I think the memory is not properly freed.

The `fluid` pointer needs to be destructed while you are exiting your activity. I would like to recommend writing another function as follows.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_ui_fluidSimulation_FluidLib_destroy(JNIEnv *env) {
    delete fluid;
}
```

And call this function in your `Activity`'s `onPause` or `onDestroy` function.

I hope that will destroy the memory reference and will avoid the `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` crash issue that you are having.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried it and I am still getting the same error - I ended up putting a Log when `fluidCreate` is first called and initially I get `fluid = 0` then I call your suggested method in onPause - Log confims it is called, then I start a new fluid session and check the pointer value before calling `fluidCreate` and even after using your method the log reads that the value of fluid is:  `fluid = -1065261744`

Comment: I think this is expected. When you have deleted the reference for the `fluid`, it should have an invalid memory location and hence while you are trying to get the `fluid` in your log, before creating it again, it is giving you `-1065261744` - that is expected I would say.

Comment: I was wondering if some other variables in the `fluidCreate` function were not freed properly.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for my ignorance, I have very little experience with C++! You're correct, when I Log after the `fluidCreate` method, the pointer is reassigned. I will keep looking into this.

Comment: The only additional thing to note is that I have a method that is called every frame to add the fluid to the screen and it crashes here. However, the only params it takes is fluid and a timestamp as so: `fluidOnFrame(fluid, t);`. So I am still convinced that the `fluid` pointer is somehow the cause...

Comment: Can you please post that function? Looks like you need to check if the `fluid` is pointing to a valid memory location before you are doing any operation on that.

Comment: Sure, I have added the additional info. Thanks again.

Comment: What are you doing inside `fluidOnFrame`?

Comment: `fluidOnFrame` is as follows: `void fluidOnFrame(void* fluidPtr, double frameTime_ms);` That's all I know, as the function is defined in the C++ library and I only have binaries...

Comment: Then before passing the pointer to that function, just check if it has a valid memory address.

Comment: So when initially calling `fluidCreate` for the first time, the pointer is `0`, then after `fluidCreate` is called the pointer in this example has a value of `-1065261680`. This value is then passed to `fluidOnFrame` and the fluid pointer is the same value. Then we back out and re-enter, the pointer holds the value `-1065261680` and then after `fluidCreate` is called, the pointer now holds a new value of `-1139431976`, then fluidOnFrame is called and again, the same value is found when using Log, however the crash still happens...

Comment: I added more info - in summary, I believe there to be a bug in the C++ library for `fluidOnFrame`

Comment: The negative addresses are always invalid memory addresses. Hence, I would recommend a `new fluid` every time you are passing the attribute to the native function. Also, instead of checking for `0`, you just check for a positive number.

Comment: I think the only reason why I was getting negative address in my log, was only because I was printing `LOGI("fluid create after int = %d", fluid);` when I (possibly) should have been printing  `LOGI("fluid create before int = %016llx", fluid);` or `LOGI("fluid create after int = %p\n", fluid);` Anyway, the problem is still persisting, unfortunately.